# How to send custom value ( unique id ) in sendgrid mail request and get this value back in the webhook provider by sendgrid

Tags: python, django, twilio, webhooks, sendgrid

I am sending mail using sendgrid 6.10.0 sdk, but I'm unable to send the custom key value which I'll get back in the sendgrid webhook.

```
from_email = Email("contact@codingnap.com")
to_email = To(email)
subject = "Codingnap login"
content = Content("text/plain", "OTP for login in codingnap is 548568")
event_webhook_url = "https://webhook.site/342ff89d-fc5e-483f-a4b2-778ed144fb3f"

mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)
mail.unique_args = {
    'custom_key': 'unique_value'
}

mail.headers = smtpapi_header.json_string()
response = self.sg.send(mail)
```

Can someples give any way to send custom id to the sendgrid which I get back in the webhook

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why your webhook should return a custom id. Also, you mentioned the twilio sdk and sendgrid in the question, which one are you using as these could refer to two different SDKs?
Please provide more context in this question.

Comment: @IObert sorry for the mistake in my question, I'm using SendGrid SDK 6.0.10, and I want to send a custom unique id to SendGrid which I get back through the webhook for the logging purpose.

Comment: Are we talking about the [inbound-parse webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook)? A webhook is one-way channel in which your web apps gets notified about in incoming email and there is no way to returning data back to SendGrid.

Comment: @IObert No I'm not taking about this. I'm talking about this [Sendgrid Webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook)

Comment: Ah, I see. This webhook is called "Event Webhook". I suggest adding this important part in the question as well as in the title (that still mentions Twilio instead of SendGrid).
But I'm still wondering, did you read anywhere that you can return data from this webhook call? As said above, webhook are for one-way communication.

Comment: No I said that I want my unique_id back in the webhook payload with other default payload that sendgrid provide

Comment: I'm not a SendGrid expert, so I don't know for sure but this is the first time I hear that users can add optional parameters to a payload at their discresion.
Is it documented somewhere that this is possible or were you hoping it is but don't know for sure?

Comment: I have used this in Gupshup and Twilio for SMS sending, In Gupshup we can provide additional argument in the extra keywords and with Twilio we can send using the query parameter that will I get back in the webhook. For having the same implementation I want back my unique id. In Sendgrid I have not found it anywhere in documentation but chatGPT told that send in the headers but I still didn't got

Comment: I see. The workaround with a query parameter is smart. Have you tried this in SendGrid too?

Comment: No because I added the webhook url in sendgrid dashboard, Is there any way to pass the webhook URL in the code? either is sdk or API

Comment: FYI: I just updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I get it. You can to pass along an individual event webhook URL per `.send` call. No, I don't think that's possible.

**EDIT:** But what you can do is passing the an [Unique Argument](https://sendgrid.com/blog/categories-vs-unique-arguments-2/) with each send call and then listen to this argument in the event webhook.

[Docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event#unique-arguments)